# 'Series' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, apply

I am creating a function to place a value within specific ranges. It works fine until I place it inside a function.

```
Merged_Data = MFR.merge(Rangos_FactorRiesgo_tmp, how='cross')
print(Merged_Data)
# fr= Merged_Data.query(f"{i}.between({i}_LimInf, {i}_LimSup)")

def Intervalos(df_result):
    resultado =df_result.query(df_result['x'].between(df_result['y'], df_result['z']))
    return resultado

Merged_Data.apply(Intervalos)
```

The error is AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'query'

I am creating this function so that based on the resulting dataframes, obtain a final value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Merged_Data.apply` will apply `Intervalos` to each row of the DataFrame, and the row will be passed to the function as a Series. So it makes sense. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think you can just do `Intervalos(Merged_Data)` instead of the apply thing.

Comment: There's a slight problem with your answer: `apply` without an `axis` argument applies the function to each _column_ of the dataframe.